# ClickOnce application re-installs every time it is launched

Tags: clickonce

We have some clients that have recently reported that every time they launch our clickonce application, the application install box appears and they are forced to download/install the application. This seems to happen after they reboot. I dont have more detail than this but I do notice that they have several obfuscated folders under Apps\2.0. It seems like every time they install a new one is created. Anyone else have/seen this issue?

Comment: Are they using the same account to log on after they reboot?

Comment: @pSattele Yes they are

Comment: Are those folders missing after the restart? If so, perhaps there is a login script cleaning up their temp/user folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from the registry not syncing properly at some point which is usually caused by some application or service at shutdown. If you look at Event Viewer and see a bunch of SideBySide errors after logging in, you're in the right place. Look at the last couple of events right before the machine was powered off. Specially look for a 'User Profile Service' (Information) event. Inside it, you'll find the leaked handles although this might not be helpful because it might just but windows services. Here's an example of the error message I'm seeing:

Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards. No user action is required.

DETAIL - 
 21 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1725646947-3788579067-928477251-98342:

Microsoft has a decent article on this problem which can be found here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2713442/clickonce-application-fails-to-update

I also found a Microsoft Support forum with a working solution but it's a group policy change. Here it is. Link to forum is below.

It appears that the issue is correlated with registries going missing at this location 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\SideBySide\2.0

Please see if adding this group policy 'Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff’ helps-

The policy can be found in the group policy editor (gpedit.msc). The policy is located under:

Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->System-> User Profiles

'Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff'

Change the setting from "Not Configured" to "Enabled"

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cab966de-034c-4806-b778-f8f2cabaf7d0/clickonce-applications-all-reinstall-after-login?forum=winformssetup